# Experienced web developers, what's the learning curve like on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, web-deployment

I just began switching from spring development to ruby on rails. I wanted to know from those who have used it before, what's the learning curve, if any, on a rails application being deployed for heroku?

Are there any special needs for heroku deployment?

What are the major advantages and disadvantages of heroku?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: pretty flat learning curve, follow along the documentation and you'll have an app running in no time.

Answer (score 4):

**Heroku is the easiest possible Rails deployment.**  It's a fully managed black-box solution for your app with excellent documentation, and they are consistently improving it with an eye to usability.  Once you have a working development version of your app, it's a very short hop to being up and running on Heroku.  See the [Quickstart](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart) and [Getting Started with Ruby](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby) articles for the specifics.

The cost of this ease-of-use is a certain amount of inflexibility.  They do a good job of making things open-ended, but a one-size-fits-all approach to hosting architecture inevitably will lead to issues.  If you just have a small to medium web app with a standard relational database and common load profile this is not much of a problem.  If you need a more custom stack with various additional services (eg. redis, sphinx, rabbitmq, etc) then you'll likely be getting into third-party addons.  All of these hosted solutions and Heroku itself charge a premium over the Amazon Web Services that they are built on, which in turn charges a premium over raw hardware / colocation costs of running your own servers.  If your site scales very large not only will you be paying a huge premium, but the assumptions that hosted service providers make for the general case will inevitably not fit your particular case as well as a custom-tuned cluster.  This is why all truly massive companies like Google, Facebook, Yahoo all run their own data centers, because at that scale having a cadre of dedicated $200k/year systems engineers designing and maintaining your infrastructure pays for itself for many times over simply from the savings of moving away from commodity solutions.

But at small scale, especially during the early rapid iteration of a product, using something like Heroku means you can focus entirely on your application and have a minimum of worry about infrastructure.  One exception is if you have a lot of Linux sysadmin chops, then Heroku may not be worth the cost even early, and in that case you might be more comfortable with something like Engine Yard that still provides you with a full Rails stack out of the box, but keeps you closer to the metal.

In any case though, Heroku is a great place to start for a Rails beginner.  It's free to get started, and there's no reason you can't do a cost assessment and migrate away later when you have more experience.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by gtd is great, just to add a bit about the problems I have ran into with heroku:

When I started with Ruby on Rails and Heroku about a year ago, the thing that gave me most problems was that by default on my dev machine, Rails used SQLite, and on Heroku the default is postgreSQL.

It usually doesn't give much trouble but certain things such as `GROUP BY` work differently which led me to lots of frustration when certain things would work on my dev machine and not on Heroku. I would suggest you install a postgreSQL server on your dev machine, for non trivial apps that you are planning to deploy on Heroku.

There are a couple other things that you can't do on Heroku and you can on a VPS, I had problems when working with a payment provider which required me to have a static ip, because Heroku is a cloud service it couldn't be done, and I had to use a proxy to connect with the provider.

Also there are a couple of gems (very few) which you can't install there, and you can't install binaries which some gems depend on, although it's never been a problem for me, bear that in mind.

Other than that couple of gotchas, Heroku is the easiest place to start deploying your apps.